# How to use common base class from System.Windows.Controls.Control for the different superclasses like Button, TextBox,TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, wpf-controls

I have a base class from **System.Windows.Controls.Control** that changes Visibility, Enabled , Background, Foreground properties according to data from outside.

when I use the class like below

```
public class RsdDesignBase : Button
    {
....
}
```

It works for Button Control. I want to use same class for other controls like TextBox, Image, TextBlock but if I use like this I neet copy paste same code for all other controls.

Is there a way to use my RsdDesignBase class as base class for others controls ? Or any other way to do this.

I will paste whole class below. What it does is waits for changes in DataTag objects when they change it changes to some properties. For example  if _enabledTag.Value is 0 it disables the control.

```
public class RsdDesignButtonBase : Button
{
    private DataTag _visibilityTag;
    private DataTag _enabledTag;
    private DataTag _appearanceTag;
    public TagScriptObject TagScriptObject { get; set; }
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    protected RsdDesignButtonBase()
    {
        Loaded += RSD_ButtonBase_Loaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
        _timer = new Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
    }

    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var background = Background;
            var foreground = Foreground;
            Background = foreground;
            Foreground = background;
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render);

    }

    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_enabledTag != null) _enabledTag.DataChanged -= EnabledTagOnDataChanged;
        if (_visibilityTag != null) _visibilityTag.DataChanged -= VisibilityTagOnDataChanged;
        if (_appearanceTag != null) _appearanceTag.DataChanged -= AppearanceTagOnDataChanged;
    }

    private void RSD_ButtonBase_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor desc =
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(FrameworkElement.TagProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement));
        desc.AddValueChanged(this, TagPropertyChanged);
        TagPropertyChanged(null, null);
    }

    private void TagPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Tag == null) return;
        TagScriptObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TagScriptObject>(Tag.ToString());

        if (TagScriptObject?.VisibilityProperty?.TagId > 0)
        {
            _visibilityTag =
                GlobalVars.AllDataTagList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty?.TagId);
            if (_visibilityTag != null)
            {
                _visibilityTag.DataChanged += VisibilityTagOnDataChanged;
                VisibilityTagOnDataChanged(null, null);
            }
        }

        if (TagScriptObject?.EnableProperty?.TagId > 0)
        {
            _enabledTag =
                GlobalVars.AllDataTagList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == TagScriptObject.EnableProperty?.TagId);
            if (_enabledTag != null)
            {
                _enabledTag.DataChanged += EnabledTagOnDataChanged;
                EnabledTagOnDataChanged(null, null);
            }
        }

        if (TagScriptObject?.AppearanceProperty?.TagId > 0)
        {
            _appearanceTag =
                GlobalVars.AllDataTagList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == TagScriptObject.AppearanceProperty?.TagId);
            if (_appearanceTag != null && !_appearanceTag.IsEventHandlerRegistered(null))
            {
                _appearanceTag.DataChanged += AppearanceTagOnDataChanged;
                AppearanceTagOnDataChanged(null, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AppearanceTagOnDataChanged(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        _ = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            double tagValue;
            bool result = true;
            if (_appearanceTag.VarType == VarType.Bit)
            {
                tagValue = _appearanceTag.TagValue ? 1 : 0;
            }
            else
            {
                result = double.TryParse(_appearanceTag.TagValue.ToString(), out tagValue);
            }

            if (result)
            {
                foreach (var controlColor in TagScriptObject.AppearanceProperty.ControlColors)
                {
                    if (tagValue >= controlColor.RangeMin &&
                        tagValue <= controlColor.RangeMax)
                    {
                        Background =
                            new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(controlColor.Background) as SolidColorBrush;
                        Foreground =
                            new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(controlColor.Foreground) as SolidColorBrush;
                        _timer.Enabled = controlColor.Flashing == ConfirmEnum.Yes;
                        break;
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
    }

    private void EnabledTagOnDataChanged(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        _ = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (_enabledTag != null)
            {
                if (TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.IsRangeSelected)
                {
                    double tagValue;
                    bool result = true;
                    if (_enabledTag.VarType == VarType.Bit)
                    {
                        tagValue = _enabledTag.TagValue ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = double.TryParse(_enabledTag.TagValue.ToString(), out tagValue);
                    }

                    if (result)
                    {
                        if (tagValue >= TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.RangeFrom &&
                            tagValue <= TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.RangeTo)
                        {
                            IsEnabled = TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.DefaultValue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IsEnabled = !TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.DefaultValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_enabledTag.IsNumeric || _enabledTag.VarType == VarType.Bit)
                    {
                        var bitArray = _enabledTag.GetBitArray();
                        var singleBit = TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.SingleBit;
                        if (bitArray.Count > singleBit)
                        {
                            if (bitArray[singleBit])
                            {
                                IsEnabled = TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.DefaultValue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                IsEnabled = !TagScriptObject.EnableProperty.DefaultValue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
    }

    private void VisibilityTagOnDataChanged(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        _ = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (_visibilityTag != null)
            {
                if (TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.IsRangeSelected)
                {
                    double tagValue;
                    bool result = true;
                    if (_visibilityTag.VarType == VarType.Bit)
                    {
                        tagValue = _visibilityTag.TagValue ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = double.TryParse(_visibilityTag.TagValue.ToString(), out tagValue);
                    }

                    if (result)
                    {
                        if (tagValue >= TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.RangeFrom &&
                            tagValue <= TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.RangeTo)
                        {
                            Visibility = TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.DefaultValue
                                ? Visibility.Visible
                                : Visibility.Hidden;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Visibility = TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.DefaultValue
                                ? Visibility.Collapsed
                                : Visibility.Visible;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_visibilityTag.IsNumeric || _visibilityTag.VarType == VarType.Bit)
                    {
                        var bitArray = _visibilityTag.GetBitArray();
                        var singleBit = TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.SingleBit;
                        if (bitArray.Count > singleBit)
                        {
                            if (bitArray[singleBit])
                            {
                                Visibility = TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.DefaultValue
                                    ? Visibility.Visible
                                    : Visibility.Hidden;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Visibility = TagScriptObject.VisibilityProperty.DefaultValue
                                    ? Visibility.Hidden
                                    : Visibility.Visible;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to rethink if *"that changes Visibility, Enabled , Background, Foreground properties according to data from outside"* worth to be implement as base class. Check attached behavior, that may lead to an extra line or two in xaml, but will require much less work compared to which you have to do now if you decide to continue. You may also want to learn about different [base classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/base-elements-overview) of WPF (better find a good tutorial/book what explain them) to see how bad your idea is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add some feature to Button, TextBox, Image and TextBlock (and possibly more) and reuse that code for all classes, right?

What you're doing right now is adding a Base at the bottom of the inheritance tree. That way you can't share it with other classes. Ideally, you would want to change the System.Windows.Controls.Control, but that's part of the .NET Framework, so you can't change that...

This is the downside of inheritance...

The only possibility I see is to use composition:

- Create a class containing the logic you want. Let's call it `RsdDesign`. No superclass needed. It will look a lot like your RsdDesignButtonBase.
- Create a descendant for every Control you want to add this feature to
- Give those descendants a private member of type ``RsdDesign````.
- Connect all applicable methods of the Control to the member.

```
    public class RsdDesign
    {
        private DataTag _visibilityTag;
        private DataTag _enabledTag;
        private DataTag _appearanceTag;
        public TagScriptObject TagScriptObject { get; set; }
        private readonly Timer _timer;
        private System.Windows.Controls.Control _parentControl
    
        protected RsdDesign(System.Windows.Controls.Control parentControl)
        {
            _parentControl = parentControl;
            _parentControl.Loaded += RSD_ButtonBase_Loaded;
            _parentControl.Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
            _timer = new Timer(1000);
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        }
    
        // The rest of your RsdDesignButtonBase implementation
        // ...
    }
    
    public class RsdDesignButton: Button
    {
        private RsdDesign _design;
    
        public RsdDesignButton(...)
        {
            _design = new RsdDesign(this);
        }
    
        // You may need to hook some of the methods explicitly like this:
        private void EnabledTagOnDataChanged(object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            _design.EnabledTagOnDataChanged(source, args);
        }
    }
```

I haven't tried this, but maybe the idea helps you to find a solution.

Comment: This achived exatcly what I wanted to do. Now I can create smaller design classess and use them on different controls.

Answer (score 1):

If you derive from your `RsdDesignButtonBase` class from `FrameworkElement`:

```
public class RsdDesignBase : FrameworkElement
{
    ...
}
```

...you should be able to extend and customize it for `TextBox`, `Image`, `TextBlock` and any other `FrameworkElement`, e.g.:

```
public class TextBlock : RsdDesignBase {}
```

Comment: You should say that Control class is better if the control will manage text, templates and typefaces. https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/10/10/1177-uielement-vs-frameworkelement-vs-control/

Comment: `TextBlock` is not a `Control`.

Comment: Subclassing controls in WPF is really the last resort to customize. With all WPF flexibility (styles, templates, attached behaviors, etc.) one would rarely need custom control, unless control is very different.

Comment: "Rarely need a custom control"? Hmm...that's a bold statement that makes you wonder what kind of apps you have been developing.

Comment: Right, but `Textblock` is <special> (and I say it's a failure IMHO) and as you can look it must implement (and does) typefaces fields. The point of `Textblock` is "because is lighter than Control inherited classes".

Comment: @mm8, I've made maybe 10 controls in WPF over the last 10 years, which are either non-existent (e.g. graph) or solve very specific problems. At the same time I've hundereds different buttons, labels, lists, whatelse which don't require that. Compared to winforms, where subclassing is the main method of customization, it's *rarely*.

Comment: @Sinatr: Fair enough :)

Comment: this control actually created in runtime from an outside xaml. I know it doesn't make sense but I am developping a desginable scada program. https://github.com/icsharpcode/WpfDesigner

this is used for designing the xaml. Then when it is saved i am creating the controls on runtime. I am saving the data as json on Tag each control then parsing it while creating for additional features. I will try to use attached properties. TextBlock is not a big issue I can implement it different way.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your control does two(three) things:

- It sets a certain layout to the control (visibility, background etc)
- it deals a lot with (de)serializing and processing JSON data.
- Some of  the processing in return modifies UI properties (e.g. Hide/Show) if certain data is available or not.

Following the helpful principal of "separation of concerns" - not because it sound academic or is 'awesome', but because you don't get into a mess of too tightly coupled code - I would much rather recommend to put all of this logic into an `Attached Property` or a set of Attached properties. And to pass the control as the first argument.

You would not have to change a lot of the implementation and you could use it for virtually all WPF elements that derive from `Control` or even `FrameworkElement`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8